# Remove/strip specific Html tags using NotePad++

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

Here is my text:

```
<a class="attachment-link" href="http://www.example.com/example-example/?example_id=example-example.jpg">
```

and I want to completly remove all of it.

There are several hundrets of those entries, I want to remove all entrys

so I tried to use this regex in Notepad++ to replace with nothing:

```
<a .*class="attachment-link" href="#">(.*?)</a>
```

but it doesn't work.

I am new to using regex, I would appreaciate any help

Comment: Maybe `<a class="attachment-link" href="[^"]*">[^<]*</a>`? Hard to know since you've only given us one example and haven't told us anything about how the various instances of this are the same or different.

Comment: Assuming there's an closing tag to the anchor : `<a .*?class="attachment-link"[^<]*?<\/a>`  Note that the first .* has been made lazy by adding a ? to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created one test.html file:

```
<a class="attachment-link" href="http://www.x.com/x-x/?x_id=x-x.jpg"> Some Text </a>
<a href="#"> Some Text </a>
<article>
    <a class="attachment-link" href="http://www.x.com/x-x/?x_id=x-x.jpg"> Some Text </a>
</article>
```

I used the "Replace All" action of Notepad++:

[image]

Pattern: "[`<a\s+class="attachment-link"(?:"[^"]*"|[^>])*>[\s\S]*?<\/a>`](https://regex101.com/r/cG7zT9/1)"

And the result was:

```
<a href="#"> Some Text </a>
<article>

</article>
```